# Specific words in a string to upper case or lowercase using python

Tags: python

I have Python strings as follows

```
string1='copy /q /y /d /e /i /r /h /v /s D:\path1\path2 D:\path3\path4'   
string2='copy /Q /y /D /E /i /r  D:\path2\path5 D:\path3\path4 /h /V /s'
string2='copy /q /y /D /e D:\path6\path7 D:\path8\path9 /i /R /h /V /S'
```

I want to convert all /q,/y,/d,/e,/i,/r,/h,/v,/s to either uppercase or lowercase.

Thank you

Comment: "either" "or"? And what is the rule you want to apply?

Comment: BTW, you'll need to escape all those \ characters in the paths (or put an r prefix on the whole string to indicate it's "raw"), if you want these commands to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.split()`, iterate over the substrings, convert the ones starting with a slash to lowercase, and `str.join()` again:

```
" ".join(s.lower() if s.startswith("/") else s for s in string.split())
```

For upper case, replace `s.lower()` with `s.upper()`

Comment: Might be worth replacing `string.split()` with `shlex.split(string, posix=False)` to handle quoted filenames just so they split nicely - although redundant when rejoined - I was thinking of looking if argparse could be slightly hacked to just accumulate options without specifying, but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Use `re.sub()` with a callback, putting the flag in a group in the pattern and recasing the group in the callback.

Comment: The basic idea:  `re.sub(r'/\w\b', lambda m:m.group(0).upper(), string1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example using `re.sub`:

```
def change_case(match):
    mstr=match.group()
    if mstr.lower() == mstr:
       return mstr.upper()
    else:
       return mstr.lower()

output = re.sub(r'/.',change_case,'copy /q /y /d /e /i /r /h /v /s D:\path1\path2 D:\path3\path4')
print output #'copy /Q /Y /D /E /I /R /H /V /S D:\\path1\\path2 D:\\path3\\path4'
```

This will convert the case of the first letter after any "/".  If you really want to restrict the set of characters you match, you can just use `r'/[abcdef]'` to only change the case on a, b, c, d, e or f.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
re.sub(re.compile('/\w'), lambda x : x.group(0).upper(), 'test /a /b')
```